# Command line scripting - what to use as a newbie

Tags: shell-script

I'm on a Raspberry Pi pulling data from a Bluetooth Low Energy thermometer and passing it to an MQTT server and though I can do this in Python I want to learn some command line scripting (Bash) and baffled where to start.

The command I issue is

```
gatttool -b A4:C1:38:40:15:51 --char-read --handle=0x000e
```

And assuming connection is made I get the answer back as text:

```
Characteristic value/descriptor: 47
```

The issue is what tool should I search for to split the line and extract the value (0x47)?

*PLEASE do not provide me the code* but hints as to the commands you would use so I can have a hunt and learn by doing :-) I've learnt enough to understand the `$?` return value so `if` is the next step in error handling.

I appreciate there are many ways to do this (one more than the possible readers of this question I assume) as searching has turned up *sed*, *awk* and *perl* but somedays I need a direction to the mountain range of Linux before finding the tunnel and then the light at the end :-)

Comment: As you want to extract a pattern from a line, I guess the best tool would be [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: And whatever comand you use, you have to familiarize with regular expressions.

Comment: Where do you see the `0x47`? I see a `47`, do you also need to convert that to `0x47`? I'm afraid this isn't a good site to ask for learning materials (in fact, that is explicitly off topic). We can give you a command for this, including an explanation so you can understand it and apply it yourself next time, but since the questions should also be helpful to future visitors, giving you just a hint isn't really in scope.

Comment: To learn about. bash scripting, the [bash info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) on stackoverflow is a good place to start.

Comment: From the documentation on the thermometer software I know all data is returned in hex even though the 0x is missing.  I missed the off-topic check - sorry.  From the answer and comments I've got a good starting point for the next few days :-)  thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn scripting, you will need to learn the most common tools as well as some `bash` specific syntax.

The things that you need here are:

`bash`:

`variable=$(command)` puts the output (STDOUT) of a command in the variable.

`echo "$variable"` prints the content of the variable.

`command1 | command2` uses the output of `command1` as input of `command2`

Commands that are useful here:

- `cut`
- `sed`
- `grep` (probably)

For `sed`, you will need to dive into regular expressions. If you're serious about scripting, that is never wasted time. If the quantity of information about regex (as we call them fondly) seem insurmountable, it is worth knowing that many of us see answers here that teach them again something new about regexes.